# Use parameter in Field Calculator using QGIS Modeler 3.16

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, qgis-modeler

I would like to set a parameter in QGIS Modeler, which I can use as input in de Field Calculator.

For example:

parameter = GVG (is a string parameter)

[image]

Field calculator:

```
CASE
WHEN Grondwaterdiepte > GVG_min_su THEN 0
WHEN Grondwaterdiepte < GVG_max_su THEN 0 
WHEN Grondwaterdiepte < GVG_min_su AND Grondwaterdiepte > GVG_min THEN 1
WHEN Grondwaterdiepte < GVG_max AND Grondwaterdiepte > GVG_max_su THEN 1
WHEN Grondwaterdiepte < GVG_min AND Grondwaterdiepte > GVG_max THEN 2
ELSE 999
END
```

I would like to replace the GVG's in the Field Calculator by a set parameter so that I don't need to change a lot in de calculator when I am going to use different parameters in the same equation (and only need to change the parameter itself). However, there are some additions to the parameter to assess different attributes.

I tried concatenating the parameter and additions, by many variations like: concat(@parameter, _min_su) or parameter(concat(@parameter, _min_su), but none of them work. How can I make sure that I only need to change this parameter and not all the text in the calculator as well?

Comment: Did you also try `concat(@parameter, '_min_su')` (note the quotations added)?

Comment: @MrXsquared Yes, I tried that as well, both with and without parameter(conc...), but that also does not work.. These polygons end up with a value of 999.

Comment: Just tested and its working fine in 3.18. I suggest to delete your string input and add a new one, but do not name it 'parameter' as this might confuse the modeler with another variable called 'parameter'. Name the string input e.g. 'param'. So you have: `concat(@param, '_min_su')`

Comment: That is odd. I did everything you suggested and it still won't work. It seems that the variable cannot be found. Eventually I tried the same in 3.18, but my computer apparently crashes when using this version. However, the calculator window does show the variables in this version and it doesn't in 3.16.

Comment: Did some further testing and it is a really weird thing. Sometimes it works and sometimes not. I cannot tell what the cause is. I'd suggest to search for a doable stable workaround, not using such variables. Otherwise just keep on testing different writings and never ever touch it again once its working.